# When I run an app. I get this error: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 22.04, cinnamon

I'm trying to run BooktabZ(booktab). It's an application that allow me to read digital books but I get this error when I run it:

```
~$ booktab
/usr/share/duDat/BooktabZ/btb: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's telling you that `btb` needs libssl.so.1.1`, a shared library. Do `ldd usr/share/duDat/BooktabZ/btb` to see all the libraries it needs. Find which Ubuntu packages provide `libssl.so`, do `dpkg -S libssl.so`. Above all, consult the BooktabZ docs.

Comment: i might just have found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score -2):

Booktab.deb is available only for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, not for 22.04. I got the same problem, using 22.04.